# CUDA kernel seemingly ignoring "if" statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda, nsight

What follows is the part of my kernel that does not behave properly, then an explanation of what I've found while debugging.

```
__global__ void Mangler(float *matrix, int *map)
{
    __shared__ signed int localMap[N];

    if(0 == threadIdx.x) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++) 
            localMap[i] = -1;
    }

    __syncthreads();

    int fn = ...; // a lot of code goes into this number, skipped for clarity
    int rnumber = threadIdx.x;

    int X = atomicCAS(&localMap[fn], -1, rnumber); // Spot of bother 1

    if(X == -1) // Spot of bother 2
    {
        // some code
    }
    else 
    {
        // other code
    }
}
```

I've found in the documentation that `atomicCAS(*address, compare, value)` basically returns (and saves to the given address) the result of `(old == compare ? value : old)`, where old is the value at the address before executing the function.

Going with this, I believe that executing `int X = atomicCAS(&localMap[fn], -1, rnumber);` should have two possible outcomes (according to NVidia Cuda C Programming Guide):

- if `localMap[fn] == -1` then `X` should have a value of `rnumber` and `localMap[fn]` should have a value of `rnumber`. *This does not happen.*
- if `localMap[fn] != -1` then `X` should be set to the value of `localMap[fn]` and said value should be left intact.

What happens instead, as debugging with NSight has shown me, is that `X` is being assigned -1, while `localMap[fn]` is being assigned the value of `rnumber`. I do not understand that, but as you can see in my code, I've changed the `if` to catch this situation.

Which brings me to spot of bother number 2: though NSight shows the value of `X` as -1, the `if {}` is being completely skipped (no breakpoints within hit whatsoever) and execution jumps straight to `else`.

My questions:

- <s>Do I misunderstand `atomicCAS` completely?</s> *yes, I did*
- What could cause and `if` which should evaluate as true to jump straight into `else` in device code?

I'm using NVidia CUDA 5.5, Visual Studio 2012 x64 on Windows 8, NVidia Nsight Monitor Visual Studio Edition 3.1. The GPU for the machine is NVidia GeForce GTX 550 Ti.

I've tried changing the syntax to `if(X!=-1)`; the true branch of the if is still not being executed.

Comment: Is the debugger telling the truth?

Comment: While I appreciate the philosophical aspect of this question, could you suggest a way of confirming whether it does? I can't think of any, seeing as debugging device code is a pain to begin with. It generally didn't seem to tell any thinly veiled lies thus far.

Comment: Also, the value of X is later used as an array index (within `else`), and it results in a memory access violation, which is consistent with a -1 slipping in there.

Comment: One way to tell if the debugger is "telling the truth" is to insert some `printf` statements in your `if` and `else` paths.  Are you compiling this code with the `-G` switch?  Also, if `X` evaluates differently for different threads within a warp, things may be confusing depending on which thread you have in focus, or which version of X you are inspecting.

Comment: I was under the impression that printf statements just didn't work in device-side code, your suggestion has pretty much solved most of my problems; yes, I do compile with `-G`, but apparently NSight _does_ lie through it's teeth. I've verified how particular blocks and threads behave and it's logical now. Thank you.

Comment: I seem to remember that if there is divergence in an `if` conditional, the `else` part is executed first.

Comment: @PawelJ.Wal Without a reproducible no one will be able to provide a full answer. Even in debug builds nvcc enables some optimizations which can result in re-ordering of statements or use of predication to flatten flow control. These optimizations can hinder debugging. I recommend you use one of the CUDA debuggers to isolate the first thread that will take the path and single step the assembly code (not PTX, not source) and determine if the compiled code is correct. As Roger commented the execution model commonly takes the else or not taken path first for divergent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc, `atomicCAS` returns the old value, that means, that in your list, your two outcomes are wrong. Your `X` will always be set to the old value of `localMap[fn]`, regardless which value it had. What is set according to the comparison with the -1, is the new value of `localMap[fn]`. When it is -1, it is set to `rnumber`, else it is left intact.

So the behaviour you see with the values of `X`, `rnumber` and `localMap` are as expected.

I cannot help with your second problem, as I dont use NSight, and dont know how it works - according to your code, your true branch should be evaluated (but be careful: your false branch also - as it is multi threaded some threads can have the condition evaluated to true, and some to false - my guess/assumption would be that you must tell somehow your debugger which thread/warp/block you want to debug and you looked at the false).

Comment: Thank you for explaining `atomicCAS`, the syntax in the docs had me in a bind. Problem is that the true branch never seems to be executed, whether or not it should be, regardless of which warp I'm looking at.